# How to center a rotatebox table-cell?

Tags: tables, rotating, vertical, cell

I have created a table, and I have fixed its width, but the problem is that when I rotate the text of the cell by using `\rotatebox`, the text did not place in the center of the cell. who can I change its place ?
My table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}









\begin{center}
\begin{table*}[htp]
%\scriptsize        
\centering
%\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}


\begin{tabular} {|p{0.04\textwidth}|p{0.04\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.02\textwidth}|} 
\hline


Text text text text
&

Text text text text
&

Text text text text
& 

Text text text text
& 

Text text text text
\\ \hline

{\multirow [c]{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{ {Example 1} }}}  & 
%[origin=c]
{\multirow [c]{3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{ Example 2 }}}


 & 

Text text text text
& 
Text text text text
& 

%\begin{tabular} {@{}l@{}}
%\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
 
Text text text text

Text text text text
%\end{tabular}


 & 
 
 

%\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}

Text text text text
Text text text text
Text text text text

%\end{tabular}  

  & 
Text text text text
Text text text text
Text text text text
Text text text text
& 
Text text text text

& r1 \\ \cline{3-9}&  & 

Text text text text
& 
Text text text text
& 
 
 
 
 %\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}


Text text text text
Text text text text
%\end{tabular}

& 

Text text text text
&

Text text text text& 

Text text text text
& 

r2 \\ 


\cline{1-1} \cline{3-9} 

{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ Feedback }}  &  
&
Text text text text

 &
Text text text text
& 
Text text text text

& 
Text text text text

& Text text text text

& 
%\multicolumn{1}{c|}{
//
%} 
& 

r3 

\\ 
\hline

{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{   Example 3    }} & 

{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ Example 4 }} 
& 
Text text text text
&
Text text text text
& 
%\begin{tabular} {@{}l@{}}
Text text text text
 Cost. 
%\end{tabular}
&
Text text text text
& 
Text text text text
& 
Text text text text

& 


r4 

\\ \hline

\end{tabular}

\end{table*}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I wan't to change the replace of the word example1 and example2 it in the center of the cell.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

[image]

In `\multirow` command you need to set number of text lines in rows, which are spanned by it. For example, "Example 1" spans 12 text lines, so instead of

```
{\multirow [c]{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{ {Example 1} }}}
```

you should write

```
\multirow{12}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Example 1}}
```

That table is fit inside `\textwidth` I suggest to use `tabularx` table environment. Complete MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htp]
\small
\centering
\begin{tabularx} {\linewidth} {|p{0.04\textwidth}|p{0.04\textwidth}|*{6}{>{\RaggedRight}X|}l|}
    \hline
Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
&&&&    \\ \hline
\multirow{12}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Example 1}}
& \multirow{16}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Example 2}}
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text Text text text text
& Text text text text Text text text text Text text text text
& Text text text text Text text text text Text text text text Text text text text
& Text text text text
& r1 \\ \cline{3-9}
&  & Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
& r2 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-9}
\multirow{4.4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Feedback}}
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
&   & Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
&   & r3    \\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    \hline
\multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Example 3}}
& \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Example 4}}
&   &   &   &   &   &   &         \\
&
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text Cost.
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
& r4    \\
&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I changed it but still  the same problem

Comment: @Zarko I don't know who would down vote this answer and for what reason? I worry the author of the question did that by mistake.

Comment: @Brm-Covißio If you think this answer is not helpful, you may not accept it and leave it as it is, with neither up or down voting it, at least for the effort it took to be posted.

Comment: @Brm-Covißio, what you changed? Where you changed? My MWE as it is, works as shown on picture in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @Zarko.

Comment: @hesham I didn't down vote.

Comment: @Brm-Covißio Sorry, that was a guess. I just thought it could be someone who didn't mean it.

Answer (score 3):

With the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 4.1), you have a command `\Block` which centers its content mathematically in the merged cells (you don't have to count the text lines). Moreover, you have a keyword `\rotate` to rotate the content of the block.

You have also a key `hvlines` which draws all the rules *excepted in the blocks* (so, you don't have to use `\cline`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
\small
\centering
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit=2pt,cell-space-bottom-limit=2pt}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright}p{#1\textwidth}}
\begin{NiceTabular}{P{0.04}P{0.04}P{0.12}P{0.12}P{0.12}P{0.12}P{0.12}P{0.12}C}[hvlines]
Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
& & & & \\
\Block{2-1}{\rotate Example 1}
& \Block{3-1}{\rotate Example 2}
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text Text text text text
& Text text text text Text text text text Text text text text
& Text text text text Text text text text Text text text text Text text text text
& Text text text text
& r1 \\ 
&  
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
& r2 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{C}{\rotatebox[origin=b]{90}{Feedback\vphantom{p}}}
&   & Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
&   & r3    \\
\multicolumn{1}{C}{\rotatebox[origin=b]{90}{Example 3}}
& \multicolumn{1}{C}{\rotatebox[origin=b]{90}{Example 4}}
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text Cost.
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
& Text text text text
& r4    \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

An easier way that worked for me is adding spaces to manually center the text (`\hspace{XXcm}`):

```
\multirow{12}{*}{ \rotatebox[origin=c]{90} {Example 1 \hspace{1cm} } }
```